# How to change default date_format in MemSQL 4.0

Tags: singlestore

Is there a way to change the default date_format in MemSQL -  I'd like to change it to "%m/%d/%Y" instead of the default "%Y-%m-%d", so that i can load data in that format from csv files.

I got error message when try to set it.

mysql> SET @@GLOBAL.date_format = '%m/%d/%Y';
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'date_format' is a read only variable

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MemSQL follows MySQL for a lot of system variables and as you can see in their docs the default date_format variable is unused: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_date_format

Furthermore, currently MemSQL does not support transforming a particular column during a load.

Keep an eye out to some awesome solutions to this and other similar problems in our next release.

Comment: Thank you Carl.  Can't wait to see the next release of MemSQL.